# Selenium 2: Store webdriver instance id of open window to create new webdriver instance with this id

Tags: java, browser, window, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

This question is about the Java API of Selenium 2 RC2, used with Firefox 4.

Let's say i have a `WebDriver` instance open and made some interactions in that browser window, like opening a URL, clicking on a link and filling out a form.

Is it possible to create a new `WebDriver` instance which uses the already open window? Something like this (pseudo code):

```
WebDriver webDriver1 = new FireFoxWebDriver();
webDriver.doSomeStuff();
String webDriverInstanceId = webDriver.getId();

WebDriver webDriver2 = new FireFoxWebDriver(webDriverInstanceId);
webDriver.continueDoingMoreStuffInSameWindow();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "attach to an existing instance of a browser" functionality in the Selenium WebDriver API yet. This is true regardless of whether WebDriver or a different process started the instance of the browser you want to attach to. There is an [open feature request](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18) for it.

Comment: is there a way to use the same webdriver object for multiple tests/classes when run within a testng suite?  

What I mean is to start the WebDriver instance with one class, but continue using it over subsequent classes/tests in the suite?